# Correcting Deconvolution Layer in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, stride, deconvolution

I was trying to build a Variational Auto Encoder with Tensorflow. I started with the simplest model. I have the following method:

```
def conv_layer(x, w_shape, b_shape, padding='SAME'):
    W = weight_variable(w_shape)
    tf.summary.histogram(W.name, W)

    b = bias_variable(b_shape)
    tf.summary.histogram(b.name, b)

    # Note that I used a stride of 2 on purpose in order not to use max pool layer.
    activations = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding=padding) + b)
    tf.summary.histogram(activations.name, activations)
    return activations

def deconv_layer(x, w_shape, b_shape, padding="SAME"):
    W = weight_variable(w_shape)
    tf.summary.histogram(W.name, W)

    b = bias_variable(b_shape)
    tf.summary.histogram('bias', b)

    x_shape = tf.shape(x)

    out_shape = tf.stack([x_shape[0], x_shape[1], x_shape[2], w_shape[2]])
    # Note that I have used a stride of 2 since I used a stride of 2 in conv layer.
    transposed_activations = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(x, W, out_shape, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding=padding) + b
    tf.summary.histogram(transposed_activations.name, transposed_activations)
    return transposed_activations
```

And the model of the whole network is as follows:

```
with tf.name_scope('conv1'):
    conv1 = conv_layer(image, [3, 3, 3, 32], [32])
with tf.name_scope('conv2'):
    conv2 = conv_layer(conv1, [3, 3, 32, 64], [64])
with tf.name_scope('conv3'):
    conv3 = conv_layer(conv2, [3, 3, 64, 128], [128])
with tf.name_scope('conv4'):
    conv4 = conv_layer(conv3, [3, 3, 128, 256], [256])

with tf.name_scope('z'):
    z = conv_layer(conv4, [3, 3, 256, 256], [256])

with tf.name_scope('deconv4'):
    deconv4 = deconv_layer(z, [3, 3, 128, 256], [128])
with tf.name_scope('deconv3'):
    deconv3 = deconv_layer(deconv4, [3, 3, 64, 128], [64])
with tf.name_scope('deconv2'):
    deconv2 = deconv_layer(deconv3, [3, 3, 32, 64], [32])
with tf.name_scope('deconv1'):
    deconv_image = deconv_layer(deconv2, [3, 3, 3, 32], [3])
```

I am getting my images from a `FIFOQueue` and feeding them into this model. My images size is `112, 112, 3`. My problem is when changing the strides from 
`[1, 1, 1, 1] to  [1, 2, 2, 1]` in both **conv** and **deconv** layers I got the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Conv2DSlowBackpropInput: Size of out_backprop doesn't match computed: actual = 4, computed = 2
     [[Node: deconv4/conv2d_transpose = Conv2DBackpropInput[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", padding="SAME", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](deconv4/stack, deconv4/Variable/read, z/Relu)]]
     [[Node: deconv1/add/_17 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_85_deconv1/add", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

P.S: I know I am missing the activation function at the deconv layer, but I guess this has nothing to do with the error I'm getting.
Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: I have got same error. Have you resolved it?

Comment: @freude, hope my answer makes sense to you. Please like if you are convinced.

Comment: @freude, I have fine tuned the solution. I forget to mention the problem with the output shape. Kindly review the final answer and accept it if you were convinced!! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this error was the following:

If we assume that we have `stride = 2` at each conv layer, then, in my case, when the input image has a size of `112, 112, 3`, after each `conv layer` the size of the `frames` or the `feature maps` after applying the convolution reduces by half. That is, after `conv1` the size (height, width) of the images become `[56, 56]`. After `conv2`, the size become `[28, 28]`. After `conv3`: `[14, 14]`, after `conv4`: `[7, 7]`. Thus, applying one additional `conv layer` named `z` has reduced the dimensions to `[3, 3]`. Here is the problem: 7 is not divisible by 2. So we get a different dimension. going from `[3, 3]` to `[112, 112]` is impossible since after applying `deconv layer`. Furthermore:

```
[3, 3] -> [6, 6] -> [12, 12] -> [24, 24] -> [48, 48]
```

Second mistake: the output shape in the `deconv layer` should be as follows:

```
# we should multiply x_shape[1] and x_shape[2] by 2. 
out_shape = tf.stack([x_shape[0], x_shape[1] * 2, x_shape[2] * 2, w_shape[2]])
```

Therefore, the final `deconv layer` becomes as follows:

```
def deconv_layer(x, w_shape, b_shape, is_training, padding="SAME", activation='selu'):
    W = weight_variable(w_shape)
    tf.summary.histogram("weights", W)

    b = bias_variable(b_shape)
    tf.summary.histogram('biases', b)

    x_shape = tf.shape(x)
    # output shape: [batch_size, h * 2, w * 2, input_shape from w].
    out_shape = tf.stack([x_shape[0], x_shape[1] * 2, x_shape[2] * 2, w_shape[2]])
    # Note that I have used a stride of 2 since I used a stride of 2 in conv layer.
    if activation == 'selu':
        conv_trans = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(x, W, out_shape, [1, 2, 2, 1], padding=padding) + b

        transposed_activations = tf.nn.elu(conv_trans)

    else:
        conv_trans = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(x, W, out_shape, [1, 2, 2, 1], padding=padding) + b
        transposed_activations = tf.nn.sigmoid(conv_trans)

    tf.summary.histogram("transpose_activation", transposed_activations)
    return transposed_activations
```

Therefore, the size of the output is different from the size of the input and this is why I'm getting the error. And in order to do `back propagation` we need a cost function. This cost function will depend on the `output` and the `input`. Therefore, if they have different sizes, that would lead to an error.

The way this could be solved is by letting the `conv layer, z,` to have a `stride of 1`.